# Memory Error in Python Primality Testing program

Tags: python-3.x, primality-test

def repeated(m, result, a, s, d):

```
check = True
r = 0
while r <= s - 1:
    if result == m - 1:
        check = False
        return check
    result = (result ** 2) % m
    r = r + 1
return check
```

I need to write a primality testing python program to test very large numbers, like at least 100-digit numbers. The code above is part of the code for Miller Rabin deterministic primality test for repeated squaring. It works really slow for large numbers. How can I speed it up? It is for a project. Thanks!

Comment: m is the number to be tested, result is (base ** d) % m, where d is the odd number after repeatedly dividing m by 2, a is the base, s is the exponent of 2 found after repeatedly dividing m, d is the odd number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is probably the `(result ** 2) % m`, use the 3 argument version of [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) that do the same but more efficiently because the algorithm use is the [Modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Memory-efficient_method) and that is much better than first doing `x**n` and then calculate its modulo. this way you are guaranty to never have a number bigger than `m` while if you do `(x**n) % m` you can have that `x**n` is very much bigger than `m` that may be the cause your problems

Also no need for the `check` variable and you don't use `a`. 
Also as you go from 0 to s-1, better use range

```
def repeated(m, result, s, d):
    for r in range(s):
        if result == m - 1:
            return False
        result = pow(result, 2, m )
    return True
```

Now for this part of the [test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Deterministic_variants)

if [image: MR test]

you need `a`, `d`, `s`, and `n` this is how I would do it

```
def mr_check(n,a,s,d):
    result = pow(a,d,n)
    if result == 1 :
        return False
    for r in range(s):
        result = pow(result,2,n)
        if result == n-1:
            return False
    return True
```